# Error C2955 while coding a Queue template class

Tags: c++

Making a queue class using templates for my data structures class. I'm getting a C2955 "Queue - use of class template requires template argument list" when I build, among a bunch of other errors which I think spawn from this one. I've compared this program to others which used templates and I can't seem to figure out what's different about this. Can anyone help me through it?

```
//Queue.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"

using namespace std;

//Default constructor for Queue object
template<class ItemType>
Queue<ItemType>::Queue() {
    front = 0;
    back = 0;
    count = 0;
}

//Check if the queue is empty
template<class ItemType>
bool Queue<ItemType>::empty() const {

    if (count == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Remove the first item in the queue
template<class ItemType>
bool Queue<ItemType>::dequeue() {

    int p = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        items[i] = items[i + 1];
    }

    count--;

    if (p > count) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }

}

//Add an entry to the beginning of the queue
template<class ItemType>
bool Queue<ItemType>::enqueue(const itemType &item) { 

    count++;
    items[count - 1] = item;

    return true;
}

template<class ItemType>
bool Queue<ItemType>::peekFront(itemType &item) const {
    item = items[0];
    return true;
}

template<class ItemType>
int Queue<ItemType>::getSize() const {
    return count;
}
```

There are no apparent syntax errors in Queue.cpp that I can find. I know that back and front aren't used but I'm not sure what they're meant for yet. Our professor provided us with most of the header file, and the main.

```
//Queue.h
#ifndef _QUEUE
#define _QUEUE
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_SIZE=10;
typedef int itemType;

template <class ItemType>
class Queue {
public:
    Queue();  // Constructor. Initialize front=0, back=0, count=0 
    bool empty() const; // To test if the queue is empty. Return true if it          is, flase if it is not. 
    bool dequeue(); // Remove the front entry from the queue
    bool enqueue(const itemType &item); // Add new entry called item at the     back of the queue. 
    bool peekFront(itemType &item) const; // Retrieve the front entry from the queue
    int getSize() const ;  // To get the number of the entries in the queue


    vector<itemType> toVector() const  // to convert the queue to a vector
    {
        vector<itemType> vectorQ;

        int i=front;
        int size=count;
        while (size>0)
        {
            i=i%MAX_SIZE;
            vectorQ.push_back(items[i]);
            i++;
            size--;
        }
        return vectorQ;

    }

private:
    int front, back; 
    int count;
    itemType items[MAX_SIZE];  // items is a circular array to store the queue.

};

#endif
```

In the main, when "Queue q;" is called to make an empty queue object, there is a red line saying "argument list for class template "Queue" is missing

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Queue.cpp"

using namespace std;

void displayQ(Queue & queue)
{
    cout << "The queue contains :\n" ;
    vector<int> queueItems=queue.toVector();
    for (int i=0; i<queue.getSize(); i++)
    {
        cout <<queueItems[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}    

int main()
{
    Queue q;  //create an empty queue

    bool flag=q.empty(); // To test if the queue is really empty.
    if (flag)  
        cout <<"The queue is empty.\n";

    q.enqueue(1);  //To test the enqueue function by inserting a set of numbers (1-10) into q. 
    q.enqueue(2);
    q.enqueue(3);
    q.enqueue(4);
    q.enqueue(5);
    q.enqueue(6);
    q.enqueue(7);
    q.enqueue(8);
    q.enqueue(9);
    q.enqueue(10);
    displayQ(q);  // Display the contents in q.

    int buffer;   // To test the peekFront function. The buffer should hold the the value of the front entry  
    q.peekFront(buffer);
    cout << "The front entry of the queue is " << buffer << " .\n";

    flag=q.enqueue(11); // To test the returned value of the enqueue fnction. It returns flase when the q has no room 
    if (!flag)
        cout << "The queue is full. No room for insertion.\n";

    q.dequeue(); // To test the dequeue function. Remove the first two entries from the q.
    q.dequeue();
    displayQ(q);  // Display the contents in q.

    q.enqueue(11);  // Does the q have room to hold two more new entry?
    q.enqueue(12);
    displayQ(q);  // Display the contents in q.

    q.peekFront(buffer); // what's the front entry of the q now?  
    cout << "The front entry of the queue is " << buffer << " .\n";

}
```

Other errors I get when building are C2662 and C2244

Comment: Don't `#include "Queue.cpp"`. Never include `.cpp` files.

Comment: `#include "something.cpp"` is generally not good because it may lead to linker error for multiple definition.

Comment: Also don't `using namespace std;` in a header file. That's a very bad bad bad bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you have to add template argumet list to use `Queue`.

Change

```
void displayQ(Queue & queue)
```

to

```
template<class itemType>
void displayQ(Queue<itemType> & queue)
```

Then, change

```
Queue q;  //create an empty queue
```

in `main()` to

```
Queue<int> q;  //create an empty queue
```

Finally, change

```
return false
```

in `bool Queue<ItemType>::dequeue()` to

```
return false;
```

(add a semicolon)

Also you should remove `#include "Queue.cpp"` and move the implementations of member functions in `Queue.cpp` to `Queue.h` because including `.cpp` is generally considered as bad because it may lead to linker error for duplicate definition, and temlate functions cannot be used if they are in different translation unit.

One more point: The comment says that

```
flag=q.enqueue(11); // To test the returned value of the enqueue fnction. It returns flase when the q has no room
```

but actual implementation

```
//Add an entry to the beginning of the queue
template<class ItemType>
bool Queue<ItemType>::enqueue(const itemType &item) { 

    count++;
    items[count - 1] = item;

    return true;
}
```

doesn't do what is said in the comment and cause out-of-range access.
You should do one of these:

- Inclease `MAX_SIZE` to a value that is large enough.
- Implement error checking.

Comment: Thanks, that did get rid of the 2955 error. But now I'm getting a C2143 at the     vector<itemType> etc.. in the header file, as well as a C4430 in the same spot. It says int assumed

Comment: [working code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/c1jUog81B7CtMUNW) This also worked with VC2008 with `/EHsc` option (without the option I got warning C4530)